# What is missing in my Dll (fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: )

Tags: c++, dll

I have created the Dll for a functionality.

Now the client given me the test harness and i added my dll into that . But there is no luck, it says that the
fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at

But then i added the visual studio project created within the Dll into the test harness solution and also copied my files in the same folder. Then compiled the test harness soliution. Then I could see the dlll getting loaded properly.
There is a call within the test harness like dll->GetInfo(). I can see the My dll is getting called when i put the breakpoint at this point.

Comment: Is the DLL built with the same version of visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not resolved as I was giving .dll instead of .obj in the Project settings -> c++ -> Linker-> .

Thanks for all comments !